# Pods with slow connection to internet

Tags: kubernetes

We have been observing really slow connection to the internet for some of our pods. Part of their init job is to download some translation files, each of them is in the 5~10kb, with a maximum of 20 parallel downloads. We have observed that for the problematic pods, downloading one of these files takes 20+ seconds.

This happens only to some pods inside of a deployment, most of the pods would have a regular DL speed. The problematic pods are not always placed on the same node / node-pool.

When a pod is having such issues, if I ssh to the underlying node and run download tests on the same target server, I get regular speeds (200M up / 350M down).

I'm pretty stuck on what to do next to find the root cause of the issue. Would be glad to get a little help ;)

More info on our setup:

- Running on GKE
- Network policies are activated with calico
- Pods only have a private IP and go through cloud NAT to reach the public internet

Comment: "downloading one of these files takes 20+ seconds." - How do you measure this time?

Comment: Hi!
We have debug log entry as soon as the download function is called, and one once the file is downloaded. This could obviously leave place to non-network errors.

Comment: Is this be possible that the pod's CPU is throttled?

Comment: The pod is running at 50% of the requested CPU capacity max, and the underlying node is at maximum 20% its CPU usage. The slowness of the process causes the init to never complete. Therefore the liveness probe fails. This causes the pods with our issue to continuously stay in a CrashLoopBackOff state.

Comment: How about the server from where the files are being downloaded. Maybe it has some problems. Have you tried load testing it? Or maybe you need to add some timeout and retry mechanism in your code.

Comment: The files are on Google Cloud Storage buckets. Tried to load test from a node on which a failing pod was with 100 parallel downloads of 5Mb files from the same bucket multiple times and there were no issues there.
We could extend the readiness probe timeout to make it work, but there is still some issues with the pod if it takes 20~30s to download a 5kb file.

Comment: How about you try to sleep for a few sec before starting a download. That way we give k8s some more time to propagate changes to iptables (Do you have a default deny policy?). If this solves it then we will know its k8s issue. If it doesn't solve it, then we still won't know whats the problem. It's very hard to debug anything over the stackex comments.